# Eliminate some value from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want to eliminate the value of matrix t3 which is <=2 without using if, for, while, repeat.
Actually I need to use on a much larger matrix, but use this as a simple example

```
t1=matrix(1:3,nr=3,nc=3,byrow=FALSE)

t2=matrix(1:3,nr=3,nc=3,byrow=TRUE)

t3=matrix(t1^2+t2^2,nr=3,nc=3)
```

Comment: when you do the operation on matrices of equal dimension,`t1^2+t2^3`, you actually get a matrix, so, the use of `matrix(t1^2,..)` is not needed unless you wanted to change the dimensions.  Also, it would have been better if you showed the expected output as `eliminate` is confusing.  Removing the `element` should break the dimensions and convert it to vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "eliminate"?  Do you just want to change the single value(s)?  Or do you want to remove the entire row?

This shows how to change all values of `t3` that are less than or equal to 2 to `NA` with the indexing assignment function `[<-`

```
> t3[t3 <= 2] <- NA
> t3
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    5   10
#[2,]    5    8   13
#[3,]   10   13   18
```

Comment: I mean remove from the matrix,but your method works for me too